# How to save UNET predicted mask as an image to the disk in Pytorch?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, unet-neural-network

AS a part of my Master's thesis, I have trained a UNET using Pytorch for detecting some objects in X-ray images. And to generate the predications, I have implemented the following function:

```
def make_predictions(model, imagePath):
# set model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# turn off gradient tracking
with torch.no_grad():
    # load the image from disk, expand its dimensions, cast it
    # to float data type, and scale its pixel values
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath, 0)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
    image = image.astype("float32") / 255.0         
    
    # find the filename and generate the path to ground truth mask
    filename = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    groundTruthPath = os.path.join(Config.Mask_dataset_dir, filename)
    
    # load the ground-truth segmentation mask in grayscale mode and resize it
    gtMask = cv2.imread(groundTruthPath, 0)
    gtMask = cv2.resize(gtMask, (Config.Input_Height, Config.Input_Height))
    
    # create a PyTorch tensor, and flash it to the current device
    image = torch.from_numpy(image).to(Config.DEVICE)
    
    # make the prediction, pass the results through the sigmoid
    # function, and convert the result to a NumPy array
    predMask = model(image)
    predMask = torch.sigmoid(predMask)
    predMask = predMask.cpu().numpy()
    
    # filter out the weak predictions and convert them to integers
    predMask = (predMask > Config.Thresh) * 255
    predMask = predMask.astype(np.uint8)
    filename = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    cv2.imwrite(Config.Base_Out+'\\'+filename, predMask)
    
    return(gtMask, predMask)
```

This function runs well for making the predictions and even plotting them. but the function `cv2.imwrite()` doesn't save the predictions as images in the passed directory, noting that `filename` already has the `.PNG` extension at the end. What could be the problem here?